# Prolog Undefined procedure and Operator priority clash error?

Tags: prolog

just recently started learning Prolog, and I have NO idea why I'm getting this error.I can't understand what can i do .

This is the 'code' :

```
?- assert(likes(a , beaf)).

?- assert(likes(b , nuduls)).
?- assert(likes(b , hotdog)).

?- assert(likes(c , sandwicth)).
?- assert(likes(c , bargar).

?- assert(likes(d , juice)).
?- assert(likes(d , chicken_curry)).
?- assert(likes(d , nudules)).

?- assert(likes(e , brade)).
?- assert(likes(e , butter)).
?- assert(likes(e , bargar)).

?- friend(e,d).
?- friend(d,a).
?- friend(d,b).
?- friend(d ,c).




?- highlyrecommended(X,L):-friend(X,Y),likes(Y,L).
?- recommended(X,L):-friend(X,Z),friend(Z,Y),likes(Y,L).



?- Is d is the friend of e ?
?- Y
?- Is e is the friend of c ?
?- Y
?-Who are the friend of d?
 a , b , e
true.
```

**This all error**

```
2 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
3 ?- |    ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
4 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
5 ?- |    ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
6 ?- ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: ?- assert(likes(c , bargar) 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: . 
6 ?- |    ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
7 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
8 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
9 ?- |    ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
10 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
11 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
12 ?- |    ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
13 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
14 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
15 ?- ERROR: Undefined procedure: (?-)/1
ERROR:   ?- is the Prolog prompt
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
16 ?- |    |    |    |    ERROR: Syntax error: Operator priority clash
ERROR: ?-
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  highlyrecommended(X,L):-friend(X,Y),likes(Y,L) . 
16 ?- ERROR: Syntax error: Operator priority clash
ERROR: ?-
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  recommended(X,L):-friend(X,Z),friend(Z,Y),likes(Y,L) .
```

**Any help please?
Thanks.**

Comment: Hint: *`?-` is the Prolog prompt. See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt*

Comment: You never type in `?-`, and you need to put your code into a file and consult it by typing `[filename]` at the prompt.

Comment: if i remove ?- then again have error 

ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: likes/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: I already consult it @DanielLyons now showing 
PROLOG: “Syntax error: Operator expected”

Is d is the friend of e ?
yes
Is e is the friend of c ?
no
Who are the friend of d?
 a , b , e
true.

Comment: *Undefined procedure: likes/2* means you don't have a predicate called `likes` which accepts 2 parameters. The *Syntax error:...* is occurring because queries such as "Is d is the friend of e ?" and "Who are the friend of d?" are not valid Prolog syntax.

Answer (score 6):

#### The `?-` prompt

The `?-` that you see is just a prompt. Python's interpreter prints `>>>`, your shell prints `$`, and so forth—it's not part of the syntax of the language, it's simply a convention adopted over the years by the language and its users. It's very convenient here on S.O. to have a separate notation for interactive queries because it gives you a visual clue as to where you should enter what you're seeing.

The upshot is that *you **never** need to give Prolog `?-`*, just other humans (for documentation or copy/pasting into emails or S.O. questions).

If we apply this advice, your code turns into this:

```
assert(likes(a , beaf)).
assert(likes(b , nuduls)).
assert(likes(b , hotdog)).
assert(likes(c , sandwicth)).
assert(likes(c , bargar).
assert(likes(d , juice)).
assert(likes(d , chicken_curry)).
assert(likes(d , nudules)).
assert(likes(e , brade)).
assert(likes(e , butter)).
assert(likes(e , bargar)).

friend(e,d).
friend(d,a).
friend(d,b).
friend(d ,c).

highlyrecommended(X,L) :- friend(X,Y),likes(Y,L).
recommended(X,L) :- friend(X,Z),friend(Z,Y),likes(Y,L).
```

#### Using `assert/1`

Prolog is unique among programming languages in that it has a built-in database. Most of the time, the database is fairly *static*, meaning the database usually stays the same during any particular execution. However, the you can modify the fact database at runtime with `asserta/1` and `assertz/1`, which insert new facts at the top or bottom of the database respectively, and `retract/1` and `retractall/1` which remove a fact or family of facts.

There is no ISO predicate `assert/1`. You have to decide if you want your new fact to be considered first or last.

**Regardless**, you do not need to assert anything in this program, because you're not changing the database from within the body of a rule. So you can just remove the `assert` wrapper you have, changing your code into this:

```
likes(a , beaf).
likes(b , nuduls).
likes(b , hotdog).
likes(c , sandwicth).
likes(c , bargar.
likes(d , juice).
likes(d , chicken_curry).
likes(d , nudules).
likes(e , brade).
likes(e , butter).
likes(e , bargar).

friend(e,d).
friend(d,a).
friend(d,b).
friend(d ,c).
```

While we're at it, let's fix your spelling.

```
likes(a, beef).
likes(b, noodles).
likes(b, hotdog).
likes(c, sandwich).
likes(c, burger).
likes(d, juice).
likes(d, chicken_curry).
likes(d, noodles).
likes(e, bread).
likes(e, butter).
likes(e, burger).

highly_recommended(X,L) :- friend(X,Y), likes(Y,L).

recommended(X,L) :- friend(X,Z), friend(Z,Y), likes(Y,L).
```

Much better.

#### Consulting a file

In most languages with an interpreter, the language works the same way whether through the interpreter or through a file. Prolog differs from other languages in this respect. Prolog has two "modes" for handling the input: a mode used by consulting, which defines facts and rules, and a mode used for querying, which is what you get when you run Prolog.

Take all the code above, properly cleaned up, and stick it in a file named "first.pl". Then run Prolog and at the prompt, type in `[first].` and hit enter. This is what you should see:

```
$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.1)
Copyright (c) 1990-2013 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- [foo].
% foo compiled 0.00 sec, 18 clauses
true.
```

You are only typing **two words** in here: `swipl` and `[foo].` Type them in exactly! Now you've consulted your first file and you can run queries.

#### Querying

The last five lines of your source are questions in English. They do not belong in your input file. You must write them again as queries to Prolog. Here's how we do them:

1. Is d is the friend of e?

   ```
   ?- friend(e,d).
   true.
   ```

   Once again, all you'll type in here is `friend(e,d).` and press enter. Try it!
2. Is e is the friend of c?

   ```
   ?- friend(c,e).
   false.
   ```

   Note that you have the wrong expected value here.
3. Who are the friends of d?

   ```
   ?- friend(d,X).
   X = a ;
   X = b ;
   X = c.
   ```

   Note that again, you have the wrong expected answer *e* instead of *c*. This time, you're going to type in `friend(d,X).` and press enter, then just typing a `;` will be enough to get Prolog to give you the next answer until it runs out.

#### Conclusion

Whatever resource you're trying to learn from, you need to slow down and maybe get your hands on another book. Prolog is far too different for you to try and blast through. Be diligent and read carefully. This question is sort of pre-basic, which is why it is so highly downvoted. We're happy to help you learn, but you have to do your share. You can't expect to get this kind of answer for every little speedbump.

Comment: Great answer in friendly words!